# Angular 12 how to convert date object to string using http interceptor

Tags: angular-http-interceptors, angular12

I am trying to convert the date property to string object for all http request. Currently converting individual request body as below;

```
modifiedOn: modifiedOn?.map(x => moment(x).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')),
```

But I would like this to apply for all http request in the interceptor. Can anyone help how to do this. my interceptor is as below:

```
@Injectable()
export class VerifyAuthorisationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(@Inject(ENVIRONMENT) private environment: IEnvironment) {}
    intercept(
        request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            map((event: HttpEvent<unknown>) => {
                return event;
            }),
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.status === 401 && error.statusText === 'Unauthorized') {
                    const returnUrl = window.location.href;
                    window.location.href = radarWebUrl;
                }
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `intercept` method before `return`. It will check if your request contains body and any `Date` elements and then converts those:

```
if(request?.body) {
  Object.keys(request.body).forEach((key: any) => {
    if(request.body[key] instanceof Date) {
      request.body[key] = moment(request.body[key]).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    }
  });
}
```